# Square Root of Wallis Product

Tags: infinite-product

How can we prove or disprove this:

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {2n}{2n-1}=\frac {2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8\cdots}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots }
&=\sqrt2\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot8\cdot8\cdots}{1\cdot3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7\cdot7\cdots}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot8\cdots}{1\cdot3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7\cdot7\cdots}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}2}&&\text{(using Wallis Product)}
\end{align}$$

According to Wolframlpha, the product diverges, and the partial product is given by $$\prod_{n=1}^m\frac {2n}{2n-1}=\sqrt{\pi}\frac {\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+\frac 12)}$$

The main objective of this question is ascertain why the Wallis product cannot be used in deriving the solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Every terms count**
\begin{align*}
  \frac{2 \cdot 4}{1\cdot 3} &= \sqrt{5} \times
  \sqrt{\frac{2\cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 4}{1\cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}} \\
  \frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6}{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5} &= \sqrt{7} \times
  \sqrt{\frac{2\cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 6}
             {1\cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5\cdot 7}} \\
  \frac{(2n))!!}{(2n-1)!!} &= \sqrt{2n+1} \times
  \sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}} \\
  & \sim \sqrt{n\pi}
\end{align*}

which blows up!!

Comment: Please explain the reason that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4n^{2}}{4n^{2} - 1}$ is asymptotic to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: That's the finte Wallis product up to $2n$ factors.  More precisely, $$\frac{\pi}{2} \sim \left( 1+\frac{1}{4n}-\ldots \right) \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}$$

Comment: Thanks - nice answer (+1).